# You have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds - MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, парсер

Здравствуйте, у меня есть парсер на c# который заносит статьи в бд.

```
private void insertData()
{
    string conStr = "server=127.0.0.1;user=skr1pt1k;" +
                     "database=study;password=11101110aA;";

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        try
        {
            string a = File.ReadAllText(@"title.txt", Encoding.Default);
            string b = File.ReadAllText(@"text_out.txt", Encoding.Default);
            string c = File.ReadAllText(@"asdd.txt", Encoding.Default);


            string sql = "INSERT INTO text (Title, Text, Tags) VALUES ('" + a + "', '" + b + "', '" + c + "')";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            con.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Иногда, когда парсит страницы выскакивает ошибка you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds...

Вот фотка бд(структура) http://c2n.me/3CA7PMx. 
Что может быть не так? Вот пример одной с ошибок. http://c2n.me/3CA7Uk6

Comment: В строках a, b и c есть что-то такое (в частности одинарные кавычки), что делает результирующую строку запроса неправильной. Можете же посмотреть что получается в `string sql`? И показать на сайте, если a, b и c не являются секретом фирмы. А вообще используйте запрос с параметрами и жизнь станет проще. Сколько об этом талдычат, а нубам что горох об стену.

Comment: С БД работал 1 день.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как справедливо вам заметили в комментариях, скорей всего проблема в том, что в спарсеном тексте встречаются одинарные кавычки. попробуйте использовать такой код

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO text (Title, Text, Tags) VALUES (@a, @b, @c)";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```